# align horizontal navigation menu

Tags: css

i have a horizontal navigation bar.
i wish to add a search bar to the navigation bar, but when i insert it, my navigation bar is misaligned.

https://jsfiddle.net/r6ntxg2f/

as you can see my menu is hovering above the green line, and the right side menu is hovering even more. i wish to align the whole menu to the green line.

```
<li id="searchbar">
  <form id="search" method="post" style="">
    <input id="bb" type="text" style="" />
    <input id="cc" type="submit" value="Search" style="" />
  </form>
</li>
```

this is how it is without search. https://jsfiddle.net/q476f585/ (working)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your sizes and padding was causing the issue, see the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wu9Lh0qr/2/) for an updated solution. All I done was updated the `padding` and `display` style. For the bottom border you will have to ensure that the other padding on the first two buttons are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the issue by adjusting padding. Here is the working code.

```css
ul#menu_left {
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  width: 75%;
  font: 75% verdana;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
ul#menu_right {
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 2px
}
ul#menu_left li {
  display: inline;
}
ul#menu_left li a {
  padding: 6px 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: green;
}
ul#menu_left a:hover {
  color: black;
  background: yellow;
  border-bottom: 1px solid yellow;
}
li#searchbar {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 6px 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
li#searchbar form {
  display: inline;
}
li#searchbar input {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu_left">
  <li><a id="tab1" href="#">The We</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tab2" href="#">Book</a>
  </li>
  <li><a id="tab3" href="#">Tab</a>
  </li>
  <li id="searchbar">
    <form id="search" method="post">
      <input id="bb" type="text" />
      <input id="cc" type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
  </li>
  <ul id="menu_right">
    <li><a id="tab5" style="" href="#">Up</a>
    </li>
    <li><a id="tab6" href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```